# submap_slices and last_frame_id is empty | Rviz2 not opening

Tags: gazebo, rviz, slam, occupancy-grid, cartographer

I am trying to use cartographer on the`ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py` but when i run `ros2 launch turtlebot3_cartographer occupancy_grid.launch.py use_sim_time:=True` rviz2 is not open and following warning occur

````
[INFO] [occupancy_grid_node-1]: process started with pid [7892]
[occupancy_grid_node-1] [WARN] [1693807084.881094372] [occupancy_grid_node]: submap_slices and last_frame_id is empty
[occupancy_grid_node-1] [WARN] [1693807085.880776465] [occupancy_grid_node]: submap_slices and last_frame_id is empty
[occupancy_grid_node-1] [WARN] [1693807086.880387575] [occupancy_grid_node]: submap_slices and last_frame_id is empty

```
````